# Script to scrape / crawl streaming url from site and JW Player

Tags: php, jwplayer6

So basically I want to scrape the streaming URL or just the token of this site

[gstvstream](http://www.galatasaray.com/)

I am able to view the URL while using inspection tool in Firefox. The JW Player generates a token on every visit and by this token the stream is playable for about 4 to 5 hours until the token expires.

I want to scrape / crawl the token by running a script and want to end up with something like "?token=ad07037e204569ae566d5dea68d6c3154692fa11061edfb0" in a flat file.

It seems that the JW player has built in logic which generates this token. Normaly I can find a JSON file or a JS script on the site which is executed just before the player and gives the player a secure token. I guess it's a built in security by JW Player. And the only way to get this token is by scraping the site i guess?

Comment: Hi @Sambir, did you find any solution? If you had a solution, please share with me. I am also stuck up by this type of problem.Thanks.

Comment: No, did not find a solution unfortunately